# How do i make it so that whenever i write something in html it will always be under the html above it using css

Tags: html, css

When I try adding something new to my html it is always above the previous things i want the what ever comes next to be under the todays matches or whatever is above it

[image]

Comment: can you add HTML and CSS code here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your html and css code.

Comment: Just use `z-index` property on your previous things. But `z-index` of your previous things must be higher than the new elements. See about [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)